# timestamp записать текущее время ruby

Tags: ruby, timestamp

В базе есть поле deleted_at типа timestamp. Для такого типа можно использовать методы, используемые для типа datetime? К примеру записать текущее время методом now() или current()

Comment: А вы пробовали?

Comment: да, не получалось, но потом выяснилось, что проблема была в другом